# JMETER-certificate is not trusted message while login the facebook account

Tags: authentication, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When I was working on facebook.com to recorded the login process using jmeter, then I came across the following error message. what should we do in such condition in order to surpass this step and directly gets login into the facebook application using the proxy server setting for the recording purpose.

The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown. (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) I believe that it'll be quite enough to clear your browser history.